# Amazon IAM User Policy To Limit Launch Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a user policy to limit launching instances to be on specific region and for t1.micro types, I tried several solutions but none work so far.

Even this one does not allow describing instance status, I create use this policy to launch the instance but I cannot use the API to describe its status, not sure what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "..",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions) aws documentation, it explains what api that does not support resource level permissions, that why the policy in my question did not work, the below worked for my case after moving some actions to use * for Resources :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {  // This allows viewing instances if user login to dashboard (does not include cloudwatch, you can add it if you want)
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {   // Users are limited to starting instances that in west region, and only micro instances
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t1.micro",
                        "t2.micro"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {   // allow user to launch instances using images in west region
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:security-group/*"
            ]
        },
        {    // these don't fall under resource-level permission, so they need to be separated in order to users to launch instances
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {   // This also cannot have resource-level permission, allows user to create images from existing running instances
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps others.